# How to call a bean after all files has been processed?

Tags: apache-camel

I wrote the following route and expected that the bean 'teaserService' should be called only one time, at the end of processing of **all** files, but ... it's called after processing of each file:

```
        <route id="teaserInterface">
        <from
            uri="file://{{teaser.dropInDir}}?readLock=changed&amp;delete=true&amp;delay=60000" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${file:ext} == 'properties'</simple>
                <to uri="file://{{teaser.config.directory}}" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${file:ext} == 'jpg' || ${file:ext} == 'JPG'</simple>
                <to uri="sftp://{{apache.ftp.user}}@{{apache.ftp.host}}/{{apache.teaser.ftp.targetDir}}?password={{apache.ftp.password}}&amp;binary=true&amp;separator=UNIX" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Dear user,\n\n the Teaser interface only accept *.jpg and *.properties files, but we found the file ${file.name}.\n\n Have a nice day,\nYour lovely Teaser interface</simple>
                </transform>
                <to
                    uri="smtp://smtp.blabla.com?contentType=text/plain&amp;from=blabla@blabla.com&amp;to=chica@chicas.com&amp;subject=A problem occured while setting up new teaser!" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <bean ref="teaserService" method="updateTeaser" />
    </route>
```

How to achieve such a behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Camel file compoment is a [batch consumer](http://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html) and adds properties to the exchange regarding the batch it is processing. You can test for the property `CamelBatchComplete` and if that is set to true, then call your bean.

Comment: Thanks Ralf! Do you have an example?

Comment: @zzKozak See the example in my answer showing an aggregator with the `completionFromBatchConsumer` option that can be used if the exchanges are coming from a Batch consumer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed only after **all** files have been read, you must sample them somehow. This can be achieved using the [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2) pattern:

```
<route>
    <from uri="file://src/data/aggregate-and-process?readLock=changed&amp;delete=true&amp;delay=60000" />
    <aggregate strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" completionFromBatchConsumer="true">
        <correlationExpression>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="direct:sub" />
    </aggregate>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:sub" />
    <!-- processing aggregated body -->
</route>
```

Please note that I set `completionFromBatchConsumer="true"`. From the Camel documentation:

> This option is if the exchanges are coming from a **Batch Consumer**. Then when enabled the Aggregator2 will use the batch size determined by the Batch Consumer in the message header `CamelBatchSize`. [...] This can be used to aggregate all files consumed from a File endpoint in that given poll.