# Apache camel create empty ctl file after all files processed

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Hi I want below flow to create an empty file once all the files are processed currently it creates after every file processed but not after all the files are processed I tried oncompletion but unable to do

```
from("file:C:\\input?filter=#testFilter")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple(newFileName+".dat"))
    .bean(LineParser.class, "process")
    .toD("file:C:\\output"+ Constants.getMapping().get(argumentName)+"?    fileExist=Append&donefileName=${file:name.noext}.txt"
```

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549924/how-to-call-a-bean-after-all-files-has-been-processed

Comment: You can add an `end()` to end the split block, and then you can write the empty filer afterwards, which then happens after all the splitting is done